# How to extract text from a Google drawing?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am given a Google drawing containing an application component architecture.  The drawings contain text used to manually populate a fairly long parameter file.  The parameter file is then used to create an AWS database instance.  I'm hoping to automate this tedious and error prone process by extracting the desired values from the drawing and populating the parameter file.

I'm using Python and just getting started with this effort.  I've been able to download the file using the mime type "image/svg+xml" but it appears the text is rendered as a vector drawing.  I've also downloaded the file as a PDF, but I still can't seem to get the text.

I'm not a master of Google drawings.  From what I've read the drawings are very simple and don't support anything like a tag that one might use to find important data.  I suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Is it possible to extract text from a Google drawing?  If so, what would be the general process flow and what mime type would I use?

Comment: If Google drawing is ``application/vnd.google-apps.drawing`` in your question, in the current stage, the mimeTypes which can export are ``image/svg+xml``, ``image/png``, ``application/pdf`` and ``image/jpeg``. Unfortunately, the text value cannot be directly retrieved. So in order to retrieve the text value from them, as a workaround, how about using OCR after downloading it? If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the input Tanaike.  Implementing an OCR solution is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation.